# Twitter streaming via PHP - how do I stop it?

Tags: php, twitter

I have been writing applications that use Twitter Streaming API. I am using TheMattHarris OAuth library I found on GIThub. This is how I typically set up my streaming process.

I call the stream.php asynchronously first like so:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
   // end of stream
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "stream.php?term="+term, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

My stream.php looks like this:

```
$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
   'consumer_key' => CONSUMER_KEY,
   'consumer_secret' => CONSUMER_SECRET,
   'user_token' => USER_TOKEN,
   'user_secret' => USER_SECRET,
));
$method = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json";
$connection->streaming_request('POST', $method, array('track'=>$term), 'twitter_callback');
tmhUtilities::pr($connection);

function twitter_callback($data, $length, $metrics) {
   // handle tweet here
}
```

The problem is that I can't seem to stop this stream. I don't know how long it runs before it runs itself out. Since this is a web application, I can refresh the page and search for a new term, but the old stream still seems to be running.

So I have two questions: how do I stop such streams? And is this the right way to implement a Twitter stream?

Answer (score 0):

I think `xmlhttp.abort()` would do the trick. You can see an example of how to do a abort button here:

http://help.dottoro.com/ljomfaxv.php

Comment: But I think this will just stop the readychange events from firing and change the readystate. The streaming, on the other hand, is happening on the PHP side and will not be affected by this

Comment: If there is no stream connecting to your PHP script, it will just cease to execute. Though I am not totally sure, I thing `abort();` is the right way to go...